# How to test if file exists with the tag <If ...> on Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, if-statement, httpd.conf

I would like to test the existence of a file in my httpd.conf of Apache 2.4.

I use the tag  like this :

`<If "%{DocumentRoot}/maintenance.enable -f">
...code to execute ...
</If>`

but my code is not good, apache's service doesn't want to start.
I have read a lot of tutorials or docs on many sites but never found the answer :(

Please help me ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should read Apache error log as it might provide some hint on how it is interpreted.

Anyway, the right syntax is: `<If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/maintenance.enable'">`

Answer (score 5):

For Apache 2.4.34 and later an alternate directive to use is [<IfFile>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#iffile).

In this case the syntax is:

```
<IfFile %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/maintenance.enable'>
... code to execute ...
</IfFile>
```