# Use Environment Variables with If Statements

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

I was wondering if there's a way to use an Environment Variables (or similar) with an if statement in order to turn certain things on and off, such as display_errors, modpagespeed.

So for example:

```
SetEnv DISPLAY_ERRORS on

<If "DISPLAY_ERRORS == on">
    php_flag display_errors on
</If>
<If "DISPLAY_ERRORS == off">
    php_flag display_errors off
</If>
```

I've spent quite a while searching for such a thing but I was unable to uncover anything which does this. Is this even possible?

I'm looking for an easy way to edit the htaccess using PHP, but instead of writing blocks to htaccess it would be easier to just change the "on" and "off" values and would also make it easier to display this as radio buttons within my application.

Comment: Was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 8):

We can be tempted to write this:

```
#SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" DISPLAY_ERRORS=off
SetEnv DISPLAY_ERRORS off

<If "-T env('DISPLAY_ERRORS')">
    php_flag display_errors off
</If>
<Else>
    php_flag display_errors on
</Else>
```

But it seems that `<If>` is evalued **before** any `SetEnv(If)`.

> Note that the value of a variable may depend on the phase of the request processing in which it is evaluated. For example, an expression used in an `<If >` directive is evaluated before authentication is done

A different working approach I have in mind would be:

```
<IfDefine DISPLAY_ERRORS>
    php_flag display_errors on
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !DISPLAY_ERRORS>
    php_flag display_errors off
</IfDefine>
```

And starting Apache with a `-DDISPLAY_ERRORS` argument to display errors or, for Apache >= 2.4, add a `Define DISPLAY_ERRORS` in the virtualhost configuration.

Comment: I actually looked at the second option you gave, but that requires the Envs to be set at the startup of Apache, which just wouldn't be possible for my application.

Comment: Just a thought: or you need to use something else than an environment variable. Maybe a file ([something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138120/how-to-test-if-file-exists-with-the-tag-if-on-apache-2-4/26138572#26138572)).

Answer (score 0):

Use SetEnvIf with early processing, this will cause your environment variable to be set earlier in the request process and then you can use them in your IF statement.

Just use a dummy condition that always evaluates to true.