# htaccess mod_rewrite default redirect if no regex match

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I enter...

```
http://mypage.info/anything
```

I would like the following:

- If the file `anything.php` exists, Apache should redirect to `http://mypage.info/anything.php`
- If the file `anything.php` does not exist, Apache should redirect to `http://mypage.info/search.php?q=anything`

Note that I'm not testing for a specific file. It all depends on user's input.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if file exists with the tag <If ...> on Apache 2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138120/how-to-test-if-file-exists-with-the-tag-if-on-apache-2-4)

Comment: Nope. I'm not testing for a specific file but any file present in my server.

Comment: You would rewrite or map based on the QUERY_STRING. The devil is in the details, which is why this is not an answer. Checking if a resource exists is the tricky part, but a naive impl would combine conditions to see if a redirect results in a 404. This is going to be complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /search.php?q=$1 [R=302,L]
```